# How did my GUID get corrupted?

Tags: c#, email, url, guid, corruption

We have a .NET (C#) web application which uses GUIDs to identify specific records in our MS SQL DB.

These GUIDs are generated and injected into the DB then used to create a response URL for the intended recipient to return to our application with.

We've checked and double checked and our outbound e-mail process is fine with all GUIDs being intact.

However, on a semi-regular basis, we're seeing invalid GUIDs in the URL's that are being requested by users.

Initially, we thought this intermittent error was a malicious "drive-by" type issue but investigating further, it seems that this is not the case. In fact, the issue is one of corruption.

We've managed to track and identify what is happening but we still don't know the how. As an example, here is one of our GUIDs and also the corrupted version of the same GUID we're seeing in the request for the page after the user receives and acts upon the email call to action.

Our GUID:

> A715395B-F235-4C29-88AE-1AFCE949E11D

Corrupt GUID:

> n7153952o-s23563-4p29-88nr-1nspr94954r11q

As you can see, the corrupt GUID has elements of the original GUID interspersed throughout but we can't see a reason or pattern for the corruption.

Our URL format is:

https://www.example.com/page/?guid1=GUID1&guid2=GUID2

When the corruption occurs, both GUIDs in the URL are corrupted and in fact, the order of the parameters are reversed so the URLs we see that contain the corrupted GUIDs look like:

https://www.example.com/page/?guid2=CORRUPTGUID2&guid1=CORRUPTGUID1

Any and all ideas as to how and why this would be happening would be most grateful. Half of the issue of solving something like this is understanding how and why it's happening but right now, we're stumped :-(

EDIT:

Additionally, there is a sort of pattern with the corruption as follows:

```
A -> n
B -> o
C -> p
D -> q
E -> r
F -> s
```

This represents of a shift of 45 characters but it does not explain the injected characters we also have.

```
Our GUID:       A715395B-F235-4C29-88AE-1AFCE949E11D

Corrupt GUID:   n7153952o-s23563-4p29-88nr-1nspr94954r11q

Our GUID:       A715395B  -F235   -4C29 -88AE -1AFCE949E11D

Converted GUID: A7153952B -F23563 -4C29 -88AE -1AFCE94954E11D

Injected chars:        ^       ^^                      ^^
```

Comment: I think is some (wrongly) applied encoding/decoding by some clients on the web.

Comment: Side note, if the guids are the primary key then this causes inefficiency in SQL Server. In that case you should use guids in the format that SQL Server considers "sequential". The .Net Guid type is not sequential. [Here is one library you could use.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RT.Comb/)

Comment: The corrupt version has artifacts from being ROT13 encoded
   `ROT13("A715395B-F235-4C29-88AE-1AFCE949E11D") =  "N715395O-S235-4P29-88NR-1NSPR949R11Q"`  I would guess a webmail client messing something up, perhaps look for commonalities in the request referrer & user-agent.

Comment: Yes, that's what we think too but identifying the how, when and where will allow us to mitigate the issue potentially. As for using the GUIDs as PK's, in this instance, no, we're not using them as PK's, we are using two GUIDs in the URL as a way of reducing the likelihood of users altering URL parameters and still getting the correct content. They're stored in the table against an incremental PK which we use for internal use. There is a 1 to 1 relationship between the GUID combinations and the PK they're associated with but for this use case, performance isn't a major issue.

Comment: Does that happen across your users or is is specific to one? If its distributed then something somewhere seems get triggered by that URL format so the simplest thing may be to change it?  E.g. change the param names and use a base64 representation of the GUIDs.

Comment: Just to add to this, it seems the the ROT13 thing is not limited to GUIDs anymore. We're experiencing errors on the system due to malformed URLs in several places now the latest being:

//www.example.com/vacancy?iframe=snyfr&cid=-1&jbid=104392&id=972517

Where the actual URL should be:

//www.example.com/vacancy?iframe=false&cid=-1&jbid=1043&id=9725

Answer (score 1):

So it seems this is down to anti-malware software some of our clients use on their inbound mail servers.

[Here's a link to a security post on stackexchange which explains the issue](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/48684/help-investigating-potential-website-attack-url-rewriting-and-rot-13-obfuscatio)